# Flutter; How to return Future List after completed async process

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I'm trying to display all object list from cloud storage with Flutter + Firebase.
I created the function for getting Future of all list of object URL in the bucket like this.

```
Future<List> _video_list() async {
    List video_list = ['!!For Debug!!'];
    firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref().child('test_videos').listAll();
    Future.forEach(result.items,(firebase_storage.Reference ref) {
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref(ref.fullPath)
          .getDownloadURL()
            .then((v) {
            video_list.add(v);
            print('-------------------------');
            print(video_list);
      });
    });
    return video_list;
  }
```

And the code for display is this.

```
class _VideoInList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _VideoInListState createState() => _VideoInListState();
}

class _VideoInListState extends State<_VideoInList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    List video_list = [];
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _video_list(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('***************************');
        List vl = snapshot.data as List;
        num vll = vl.length;
        print(vl);
        print(vll);
        print('***************************');

        return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int i = 0; i < vll; i++)
              new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return VideoPlayPage();
                      }));
                },
                child:
                Card(
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.cake),
                            title: Text(vl[i]),
                          ),
                          Stack(
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight +
                                  const FractionalOffset(-0.1, -0.1),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                    'Place : \n Date Time : \n Club : \n Video Length : \n'),
                              ]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ])),
              ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The console log is below. (URL is masked)

```
I/flutter (30430): ***************************
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!]
I/flutter (30430): 1
I/flutter (30430): ***************************
I/flutter (30430): -------------------------
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!, <Object URL1>]
I/flutter (30430): -------------------------
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!, <Object URL1>, <Object URL2>]
I/flutter (30430): -------------------------
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!, <Object URL1>, <Object URL2>, <Object URL3>]
I/flutter (30430): -------------------------
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!, <Object URL1>,　<Object URL2>, <Object URL3>, <Object URL4>]
```

It looks the object is added to list but **return** run before async process is completed.
How Can I return the fully list of objects.

Thank you for your help.

**Try to use map**

code

```
  Future<List> _video_list() async {
    List video_list = ['!!For Debug!!'];
    firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref().child('test_videos').listAll();
     await result.items.map((firebase_storage.Reference ref) {
               firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
                   .ref(ref.fullPath)
                   .getDownloadURL()
                   .then((v) {
                         video_list.add(v);
                         print('-------------------------');
                         print(video_list);
                   });
     });
     return video_list;
  }
```

Log

```
====================================================================================================
I/flutter (30430): ***************************
I/flutter (30430): [!!For Debug!!]
I/flutter (30430): 1
I/flutter (30430): ***************************
```

Comment: Try using `result.items.map` and use `await` while fetching further data from firebase. Your code is not waiting for `Future.forEach` to finish.
That might help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to use result.items.map and await. But unfortunately it's not working. I added the code and log.
Is it wrong?

Comment: Your `Future.forEach` call doesn't return the `Future`, so `Future.forEach` will not wait for the `Future`s to complete.  If you use `result.items.map()`, you need to make sure that you actually *read* all of the elements from the result since `Iterable.map` is lazy.   IMO it's simpler to just use a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

as @helloWorld mentioned you are not using await on forEach snippet.

```
Future<List> _video_list() async {
      List video_list = ['!!For Debug!!'];
      firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
          .FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('test_videos')
          .listAll();
      Future.forEach(result.items, (firebase_storage.Reference ref) async {
        video_list.add(
          await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(ref.fullPath)
            .getDownloadURL()
          );  
        });
      });
      return video_list;
    }
```

Either way you should avoid using forEach.. as dart recommendations: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls.html

```
    //you should avoid using forEach
    Future<List> _video_list() async {
      List video_list = ['!!For Debug!!'];
      firebase_storage.ListResult results = await firebase_storage
          .FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('test_videos')
          .listAll();
      //dart supports for loops with async

      for(final result in results){
        video_list.add(
          await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(result.fullPath)
            .getDownloadURL()
          );  
      }
      
      return video_list;
    }
```